# MySQL Create stored function that can declare and set select results

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I would like to gather the ids from two tables, merge those tables to use them an IN statement to find out the count(*) like so:

```
   drop function if exists listing_count;
   create function listing_count(parent int(11)) returns int(11) deterministic 
   begin 
    declare count int(11) default 0;
    declare ARRAY1;
    declare ARRAY2;
    set ARRAY1=(select id from category1); 
    set ARRAY2=(select id from category2); 
    set count=(select count(*) from listing_category where category in(ARRAY1+ARRAY2));
    return count;
   end
```

Is it possible to set and declare selected results (ARRAY1 and ARRAY2) to use later on? **I don't want to merge everything into a single query**.

Comment: Curious about why you don't want a single query. Also, what is the relationship, if any, between these tables?

Comment: I want to use the array in a while loop to gather lots of data before using it in the in statement. @PaulCampbell

Comment: Could you add in some pseudocode for this data gathering step into your question. IN() requires a comma-separated list, rather than an array, which I could show you how to create with a cursor. However, I suspect that what you are attempting could be better achieved through JOINS (and maybe temp tables) so it would be useful to see the complete picture of how you want to use this data before making any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have arrays, you can only store a single value in a variable. You can use a subquery in `WHERE category IN`, and `UNION` to combine the two tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM listing_category
WHERE category IN (
    SELECT id FROM category1
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM category2
);
```

Or use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM listing_category
JOIN (        
    SELECT id FROM category1
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM category2
);
```